# How do I benchmark and compare Simulink models when it comes to resources usage and performance?

Tags: matlab, simulink, performance

I am trying to implement a model with different levels of complexity in Matlab Simulink. I would like to perform a comparison between the different models in terms of computational cost, resource usage (RAM), number of operations and CPU time and possibly any other useful performance metrics.

What is the right procedure to this? Are there are useful functions I can use? Thanks in Advance (I am using Matlab 2015b)

All the models are Simulink models

Answer (score 1):

You can use the profiler 
https://it.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/how-profiler-captures-performance-data.html
it gives you some stats about your model